# Parsing XML with “&amp;” and “&reg;” using XSLT but still getting errors

Tags: xml, xslt-2.0

I want to decode HTML tags from a string and used:

```
disable-output-escaping="yes"
```

That was working properly until the string contained `&reg;` (meaning ®).

Then I found that a possible solution is to replace `&reg;` with `&#174;`; but it is not working.

i am using this code

```
   <xsl:if test="$ShortDescription !=''">
          <shortdescription><xsl:value-of  select="replace($ShortDescription,'&reg;','&#174;')"  disable-output-escaping="yes"/></shortdescription>
   </xsl:if>
```

The XSLT file giving me the error looks like this:

```
HTTP Status 500 - {msg=getTransformer fails in getContentType,trace=java.lang.RuntimeException: getTransformer fails in getContentType at
```

and when i am not used replace function then its give error look like:
XML Parsing Error: undefined entity at

```
<shortdescription>Wear some adventure with the same hat Indiana Jones&reg; wears in his movies.</shortdescription>
```

Comment: Be very specific about the error(s) you get.  Is there a specific error message(s) you get that you can share?

Comment: ok now i was edited my question please review again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the input file contains the entity reference `&reg;` and contains no entity definition for this entity, then it's not well-formed XML which means you can't process it using XSLT. Possible solutions include:

- add a definition of this entity by including an appropriate DTD
- replace `&reg;` by `&#174;` using non-XML technology before parsing, e.g. sed/awk/Perl
- use an HTML parser rather than an XML parser, e.g. validator.nu.